# jquery tabs not updating cookie

Tags: jquery-ui, cookies, jquery-tabs, jquery-cookie

I am using jquery UI 1.10 and I need to enable cookie in tabs. It used to work before.

But despite getting lokely lates jquery cookies 1.31 (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js) my tabs do not record a correct cookie. It does not change when I switch tabs.

Tabs are initialized as:

```
     $("#tabs").tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30, name: "userprivtabs"} });
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Worked for me

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (e, ui) { 
        $.cookie('selected-tab', ui.newTab.index(), { path: '/' }); 
    }, 
    active: $.cookie('selected-tab')
});
```

Comment: Indeed, i found the same. Havwe to write some short handlers attached to tab's events to save and restore tabs. Attach them to create and active events